# Setting UTF-8 on a php script yields HTML source code, not the rendered content

Tags: php, html, utf-8, character-encoding

When I set content type at the top of a simple PHP script:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
    echo "<P>this is a paragraph</p>";
?>
```

The page is served as HTML source code (not php, just the HTML).

```
<P>this is a paragraph</p>
```

Why is that?

Comment: I don't understand...can you elaborate? btw, are you new to php?

Comment: This has nothing to do with setting UTF-8, but with using the wrong `content-type`

Comment: Would a mod please delete this?  It was a simple overlooked type-o in my code, but there are answers that prevent me from removing.  Please delete to reduce clutter on SO.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't expecting anything else when serving the content as `text/plain`. If you want the browser to interpret this as HTML, change the header to `text/html`.

Comment: this was a simple type-o in my code, and this answer means I can't delete my mistake and reduce clutter on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Php is server-side: It will execute and send what you tell it to send.
Sending the content-type header won't affect the php output, but will affect how the client evaluates it.
In your case, even if you echo `<script>alert('test');</script>`, it won't be considered javascript by the client but only text, same goes for all html tags.

Comment: this was a simple type-o in my code, and this answer means I can't delete my mistake and reduce clutter on SO.